# É possível instalar o Python no Windows 10 sem privilégios de administrador?

Tags: python, instalador, windows-10, pip

Tenho o Python 3 instalado, porém foi feita a instalação padrão, na pasta arquivos de programas. E trabalho numa máquina com perfil de usuário, com regras rígidas de proxy, etc que já atrasam bastante criar por aqui.

Meu problema na real é que quando tento usar o PIP, depois de finalmente passar pelo proxy tomo erro de que não tenho privilégios para instalar nada na pasta de arquivos de programas. Imagino que teria que desinstalar e instalar novamente, talvez, numa pasta como a C:.

Mas a pergunta precede, é possível uma (ou todas) opções abaixo?

1. Instalar o Python sem privilégios de administrador?
2. Baixar e instalar pacotes pelo PIP em local diferente do que consta a
   instalação do Python na máquina?

Valeu!

Comment: Já utilizou ambientes virtuais do Python? Com ele você consegue instalar os pacotes de *forma local* no projeto.

Comment: nunca usei, valeu! vou dar uma estudada é tipo o que é demonstrado neste artigo?: https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/python-e-virtualenv-como-programar-em-ambientes-virtuais

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderá instalar em qualquer diretório, só terá problemas em adicionar o caminho instalado na variável path do sistema. Para isso acredito que adicionando as variáveis de usuário funcione numa boa.

Na minha estação trabalho com o python instalado através de um pacote normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Ailton, mas neste caso eu teria que desinstalar e instalar novamente o Python certo? e apontar/configurar as variáveis de ambiente manualmente na variáveis de ambiente de usuário... é de fato uma saída, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uma instalação em modelo pendrive (https://winpython.github.io/) rolou, por incrivel que pareça não precisei de autorização de adm (no windows 10) e ainda consegui usar e atualizar o pip e pacotes, inclusive usando virtual eviroments (venv).

Setei as variáveis de ambiente para meu usuário e estou com o Python rodando sem trava, podendo de fato portar as aplicações de um lado pro outro.

Recomendo: https://winpython.github.io/